# Configure keycloak admin UI to listen on different port than the IAM services?

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to configure keycloak admin UI to listen on different port than the IAM services?

My primay goal is to restrict access to admin just from dedicated ip addresses, and allow access to OAuth and OIDC clients from public Internet.

Comment: I don't know whether or not that's possible with keycloak itself, but if you put a proxy in front of it (e.g., nginx, apache, ...) you can control what paths can be accessed on what ports.

Comment: many thx, good point.

Comment: I block access remotely and only access via SSH SOCKS proxy with proxy server rule.